# Test framework quit unexpectedly - Cucumber tests

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, cucumber

after test launch the result is test passed, but test framework quit unexpectedly. How to resolve it?

**Test sample**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Test feature**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Output**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Configuration**

[image: ScreenS hot]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>test</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you need to specified the location of feature file in the @CucumberOptions.

Such as:

```
@CucumberOptions(
        format={"pretty", "html:reports/test-report"},
        tags= "@smokeTest",
        features = "Features")
```