# test framework quit unexpected, Cucumber tests Kotlin intellij

Tags: java, kotlin, cucumber, bdd

I am trying to run test cases in cucumber for testing a mobile application using IntelliJ. The project code is in kotlin and I am using appium server to run the test case on android emulator. The test cases were working fine but after taking last pull request from project repository on github, the test cases are not running
[Cannot find cucumber cli main file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O84LG.png)

I am getting Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.cli.Main

```
"C:\Users\Code Automation\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_322\bin\java.exe" "-Dorg.jetbrains.run.directory=C:\Users\Code Automation\Desktop\Test-Automation\Mobile\src\test\resources\features\profile" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=50267:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.2\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Users\Code Automation\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.3\plugins\cucumber-java\lib\cucumber-jvmFormatter.jar" cucumber.cli.Main --format org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvmSMFormatter --monochrome --name "^verify the change password components$" "C:/Users/Code Automation/Desktop/Test-Automation/Mobile/src/test/resources/features/profile/changePassword.feature"
Testing started at 6:06 PM ...
Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.cli.Main
```

so far I have tried. Deleting and restoring configurations, adding previous version of cucumber in pom.xml file, giving file path in the test runner.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52948984/10047785
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53700597/10047785
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61748652/10047785

I am still getting errors. I think this can be a problem due refactorized project after pull request. Any help in solving this issue will be appreciated.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.letshego.das.registration.mobile</groupId>
<artifactId>registration</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Visual Studio App Center appium java test extensions</name>
<description>Extensions for producing nice looking test reports for appium tests in Visual
    Studio App Center
</description>

<url>http://appcenter.ms</url>
<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>MIT License</name>
        <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</url>
    </license>
</licenses>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jcenter</id>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
    <maven.version>3.3.9</maven.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.4.0</kotlin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    <appium-test-extension.version>1.5</appium-test-extension.version>
    <io.appium-java-client.version>7.3.0</io.appium-java-client.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <mapstruct.version>1.3.1.Final</mapstruct.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <browserstack.version>1.1.1</browserstack.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.6</aspectj.version>
    <jvmargs>-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Xss1M</jvmargs>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk7</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20210307</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.55</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>30.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.897</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.897</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>




    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>automate-testassist</artifactId>
        <version>${browserstack.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>${io.appium-java-client.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-surefire-provider -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>

    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>

                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>

                <useUnlimitedThreads>false</useUnlimitedThreads>
                <threadCount>1</threadCount>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled</name>
                        <value>true</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>automate-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${browserstack.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <complianceLevel>${java.version}</complianceLevel>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.trivago.rta</groupId>
            <artifactId>cluecumber-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>reporting</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sourceJsonReportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report</sourceJsonReportDirectory>
                <generatedHtmlReportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-report</generatedHtmlReportDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>kapt</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>kapt</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                                <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                            </path>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <jvmTarget>${java.version}</jvmTarget>
                <javaParameters>true</javaParameters>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xjvm-default=enable</arg>
                </args>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                    <plugin>all-open</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
                <pluginOptions>
                    <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Entity</option>
                    <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass</option>
                    <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Embeddable</option>
                </pluginOptions>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Replacing default-compile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <!-- Replacing default-testCompile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <proc>none</proc>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportVersion>2.4.1</reportVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: My hunch.  Add this dependency

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: This was a hybrid project for both mobile and web. I was able to solve it by opening the mobile project separately in intelliJ (I had to open sub directory). So this way my project was able to locate the cucumber file and Java jdk.